# AngularJS Validation from multiple components

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I'm developing a small AngularJS (1.6) app, trying to use a component-based architecture.

[image]

On my HomePageComponent, I have three different sub-component A, B and C, which all contains different content such as input fields, datepickers and a list. It should not be possible to navigate to the next page (state) if a validation in any of my sub-components fails. The "Button A" should therefore be disabled - ex. name input field in component A is not set.

However, I can't seem to find a reasonable solution/pattern on how to achieve this functionality while using components.

Does anyone have a proper solution for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: In the HomePageComponent if you add a `<form>` any inputs and validation in your nested components will participate in the outer form validation

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a `wizard` such as [angular-wizard](https://github.com/angular-wizard/angular-wizard) . From the github page:

```
<wizard on-finish="finishedWizard()" on-cancel="cancelledWizard()"> 
    <wz-step wz-title="Starting">
        <h1>This is the first step</h1>
        <p>Here you can use whatever you want. You can use other directives, binding, etc.</p>
        <input type="submit" wz-next value="Continue" />
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step wz-title="Continuing">
        <h1>Continuing</h1>
        <p>You have continued here!</p>
        <input type="submit" wz-next value="Go on" />
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step wz-title="More steps">
        <p>Even more steps!!</p>
        <input type="submit" wz-next value="Finish now" />
    </wz-step>
</wizard>
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll look in to it.